# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction when deploying web application on tomcat on centOS5/linux

Tags: linux, hibernate, jndi, tomcat7

**Tomcat version :** 7
**OS:** CentOS-**5
Description :** Deployed a .war file /web application on Tomcat7 on Centos5 through jenkins
the deployment is successful and able to view the web application. But when i access the feature which uses the DB , below exception is thrown with no further stack trace

Exception when connecting to DB : `org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection`

DB parameters specified 
In /conf/context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/com/gtspt/vrs"
                            global="jdbc/com/gtspt/vrs"
                            type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

In /conf/server.xml

```
<Resource 
            name="jdbc/com/gtspt/vrs" 
            auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@gts-ora-rac-gns.dmz.gtspt.corp:1521/edged"
            username="XXXXX" 
            password="XXXXX" 
            maxActive="10" 
            maxIdle="10"
            maxWait="-1"/>
```

Same set-up/configuration Works on tomcat 7 on windows locally. Please guide me. i am new to linux 
.Telnet from the linux system to the db is successfull

Comment: Problem Resolved : Added some logging for the Actual  exception stack trace which pointed out missing VIP hosts in the linux/centos system. So just add the vip hosts in /etc/hosts file in ur linux system  
 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gts-ora-rac1-vip
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)